# Why do we need question mark in this rails try block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, devise

I'm reading `Rails Devise gem` documentation and it says:

> If the page could potentially not have a current_user set then:
>
> `if current_user.try(:admin?)   # do something end`

I have tried it without question mark

```
current_user.try(:admin)
```

and it works the same way returning `true` or `false`.

Do I miss something? Is there any difference and how can I see it?

Comment: by default, rails AR attributes that are boolean can either be called with or without a question mark (?). By convention, it is easier to read if you add the `?` and that also shows that it is boolean at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is somewhat unusual in that it lets you include a wide range of characters in the names of methods including `?` and `!`.

They have no special significance to the interpreter but the language convention is that:

- methods ending with `?` are *interrogative* - they should *ALWAYS* return true or false.
- methods ending with `!` either mutate the object the are called on or may raise a exception.

So why does it matter at all? In this particular case it does not matter since your user class has an accessor for the `@admin` instance variable created by ActiveRecord - just like any other column.

If it did not however `current_user.try(:admin)` would always return nil. Remember that instance variables are always private in Ruby until you provide an accessor*.

```
# Just a plain old Ruby class - not an ActiveRecord model 
class User
  def initialize
    @admin = true
  end

  def admin?
    @admin
  end
end

User.new.try(:admin) # is always nil...
```

This is because `User` does not respond to `:admin` and `.try` prevents a `NoMethodError` and just returns nil instead.

---

### ActiveRecord and accessors:

In a plain old ruby class you would add accessors to make the instance variable `@admin` available:

```
class User
  def initialize
    @admin = true
  end

  attr_accessor :admin
end
```

Which does this:

```
class User
  def initialize
    @admin = true
  end

  # getter
  def admin
    @admin
  end

  # setter
  def admin=(val)
    @admin = val
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord reads the schema from your database and uses metaprograming to *auto-magically* add accessors to your model classes. They are a bit more complex than the example above but its the same basic principle. Thats why your User model responds to `#admin`.

Comment: * - `instance_variable_get` and `instance_variable_set` do let you flout encapsulation in Ruby. But thats not really the point here.

Comment: i don't get this bit: _your user class has an accessor for the admin instance variable created by ActiveRecord - just like any other column._ `Admin` is instance variable. This is totally new to me

Comment: If you have a `users.admin` column in your database schema ActiveRecord creates a getter and setter (accessors) for an instance variable in called `@admin` in your User class. When you load a record from the database this is where the value from the database is stored.

Comment: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables

Comment: ok, this I understand. What I don't understand is that in your first answer you said that _class has an accessor for the admin **instance** just like any other **column**_ And to me it sounds like by admin you mean _column_ which is _instance_ **at the same time**. Did you mean that? Or by _admin instance_ you meant instance of **User class** with all the columns?

Comment: what I wrote was `admin instance variable` meaning that the User instance has a variable called `@admin` which it uses as a representation in memory which corresponds to a database column.

Comment: I'm just assuming here that you have a database column named `admin`.

Answer (score 1):

There is *probably* no functional difference, in this case.

I'm guessing `admin` is a boolean field in the `users` database table. So, `user.admin` will return either `true` or `false` -- no surprises here!

For each column in the table, Rails will also *automatically* generate an associated method prepended with an `?`. For example, if you have a column `foo`, then there will be a method `foo?` - which will return `true` or `false` depending on the value of `foo`.

For example, if `current_user.name == "Tom"` then `current_user.name? == true`. And if `current_user.name == nil`, then `current_user.name? == false`.

It's very rarely *necessary* to use the `?` methods in your code, since all objects are either "truthy" or "falsey" in ruby anyway. But it can sometimes be useful to show intent, and makes the code easier to read, as it's clear that the value is only being used in a boolean manner.

Comment: did you mean method called `name?`, not `column_name?`, right?

Comment: Oh, erm... Unintended confusion, sorry... If there is a column called `column_name` then there will be a method called `column_name?`. If there is a column called `name`, then there will be a method called `name?`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, rails ActiveRecord object attributes that are boolean can either be called with or without a question mark (?).

By convention, it is easier to read if you add the `?`, and that also shows that it is boolean at first glance.

So, reading this gives the impression that you are asking a question in English.

Therefore, my guess is that `admin` is a boolean field on the user.

Also, Tom above is very correct.